# How to fix apt-get update not working on my linux container

Tags: debian, apt, container

I have created a Linux Container using below command.
sudo LXC create k3_7.8 container_name

I am not able to run the apt-get update command after container creation successfully. Please see the current configuration inside the Linux container.

```
System information 
root@newContainer:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie)
Release:        8.4
Codename:       jessie
root@newContainer:~#
```

```
root@container:/var/lib/apt# cat  /etc/apt/apt.conf
Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";
```

```
root@container:/var/lib/apt# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Console Snapshot:-

```
root@container:/var/lib/apt# sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://ftp.de.debian.org sid InRelease [149 kB]
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.84.204 80]
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.84.204 80]
```

```
Do I need to update any configuration.
```

Comment: Can you actually connect to the internet when you're in the container? What kind of container is this? Docker? Something else? How was it set up? Please [edit] your question and add more detail.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your `Dockerfile` most important is the `FROM` line.

Comment: This is not docker container. This is LXC container.

Comment: @terdon can you please help. As I am not getting any response and stuck with this.

Comment: Not really, I don't know about containers. However, I do know that you need to be able to access the internet and you haven't answered my question: Can you actually connect to the internet when you're in the container? Please [edit] your question and tell us if you can access the internet.